# Using Dist::Zilla dist.ini how can I have files that I only use for testing?

Tags: perl, cpan, dist-zilla

In a Dist::Zilla-based distribution I would like to have some files that are only used for testing, but do not get installed. These are mockup libs that aren't needed for runtime.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CPAN distributions never install the `t` and `xt` directories. You can put your tests and your mock libs into `t`.

As an example, take my module [MooseX::LocalAttribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::LocalAttribute). [In the dist](https://metacpan.org/release/SIMBABQUE/MooseX-LocalAttribute-0.05/source), there is a `t/`, a `t/lib` and an `xt/`.

If you install this using `cpanm -l` into a local lib dir, you will see there are no tests installed. This happens automatically. It's just how CPAN works.

```bash
$ cpanm -l mylib MooseX::LocalAttribute
--> Working on MooseX::LocalAttribute
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SI/SIMBABQUE/MooseX-LocalAttribute-0.05.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring MooseX-LocalAttribute-0.05 ... OK
Building and testing MooseX-LocalAttribute-0.05 ... OK
Successfully installed MooseX-LocalAttribute-0.05
1 distribution installed

$ tree mylib
mylib
├── lib
│   └── perl5
│       ├── MooseX
│       │   └── LocalAttribute.pm
│       └── x86_64-linux
│           ├── auto
│           │   └── MooseX
│           │       └── LocalAttribute
│           └── perllocal.pod
└── man
    └── man3
        └── MooseX::LocalAttribute.3

9 directories, 3 files
```

Note that as long as stuff is in `t/lib` (or anywhere under `t/`, really), you do not have to hide the package names from the PAUSE indexer. It's smart enough to not find it.

Answer (score 2):

**I misunderstood the question. This answer is for the following question:**

> How do I exclude files from a Dist::Zilla based distribution so they don't get shipped at all?

You are probably using either the [GatherDir](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::GatherDir) or [Git::GatherDir](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Git::GatherDir) plugin to build your bundle. Both of them have an option `exclude_filename` that you can set in your dist.ini to not include a file in a bundle.

A common pattern is to exclude auto-generated files such as *LICENSE* or *META.json*, and then add them later with another plugin. But you don't have to do that, you can just exclude files completely.

A good example is the URI distribution. On [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/dist/URI/source), it does not include any text files in the bundle. But if you look [at the repository on github](https://github.com/libwww-perl/URI), you can see there are various .txt files such as *rfc2396.txt*. The [dist.ini](https://github.com/libwww-perl/URI/blob/master/dist.ini) contains the following lines.

```ini
[Git::GatherDir]
exclude_filename = LICENSE
exclude_filename = README.md
exclude_filename = draft-duerst-iri-bis.txt
exclude_filename = rfc2396.txt
exclude_filename = rfc3986.txt
exclude_filename = rfc3987.txt
```

As mentioned before, the *LICENSE* and *README.md* files will still appear in the final bundle, because they get added later via [@Git::VersionManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::PluginBundle::Git::VersionManager).

Comment: Thanks - but does this mean that the files will not be installed (I.e.: that they will only be used for building and testing) or that they won’t be part of the distribution at all? I understand that excluding results in the latter not the former. Did I get it wrong? Sorry - it’s about the third dist I build and I’m only getting into testing

Comment: @simone oh. I think I misunderstood. Did you mean the `t/` directory were your unit tests live? That never gets installed. `t/` and `xt/` don't get copied by the cpan (or cpanm, or whatvever) clients. Try to install any CPAN module with `cpanm -l mylib <module>`, then `tree mylib`. You'll see there are no tests.

Comment: I am going to add a second answer detailing this.

Comment: Caveat: I’m a total newbie to testing. In my module I have a DBIx::Class schema for a database, which is only there for testing. It’s sits under ./lib but I obviously don’t want it installed. How do I deal with that? Should I maybe have a ./t/lib directory?

Comment: @simone if you want to have a chat, drop me an email. I might be able to explain some concepts. :)

Comment: thanks, where do I find the address?

Comment: @simone look for something I've released to CPAN :)